# How does SetWindowLongPtr() pass a message around?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, message

I have been trying to learn how to use `SetWindowLongPtr()` and understand it as the following:

1. You can use the following function to grab the current message and send it to a custom protocol: 
   `LONG_PTR Some_Ptr = SetWindowLongPtr(Some_Hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)Custom_Proc);`
2. Create the custom protocol, example as follows:

   ```
   static LRESULT CALLBACK Custom_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
       switch (msg)
       {
           case WM_COMMAND:
               MessageBox(hwnd,"This is a window","OKAY",NULL);
               break;
           default:
               return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)Some_Ptr, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
               break;  
       }
       return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)Some_Ptr, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
   }
   ```

My questions are as follows:

1. Am I missing something here? Is this correct?
2. Where do you call `SetWindowLongPtr()`?  If you need a specific situation, imagine a button handle as `Some_Hwnd` being created in WM_CREATE. But I'ld rather it be left open to other circumstances.

Comment: I think you're confused.  According to the documentation, GWLP_WNDPROC changes the window procedure for the specified window, so any future messages sent to that window will go to the new procedure.  It doesn't "grab the current message" in any sense that I'm aware of.

Comment: Okay... I think I understand. Here's another question for clarification, assume I click a button after changing its procedure to a new one, `Custom_Proc`. Normally that would send `WM_COMMAND` with a `LOWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED`.  Does it do the same?

Comment: For a follow up question, it is a good idea to post a new question, at least if the new question makes sense on its own, as your second question does.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You should make your comment an answer, as it is the correct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Changing a window's `GWL_WNDPROC` value does not change **HOW** that window's messages operate, it only changes **WHERE** the messages are delivered for processing. And changing a button's `GWL_WNDPROC` value will never see the button's `WM_COMMAND` messages because they are sent to the button's **parent window** instead of the button's window. So you would have to replace the `GWL_WNDPROC` of the parent window in order to intercept `BN_CLICK` notifications.

Comment: Thank you so much Remy Lebeau! That makes a lot more sense now. Do you know of any good resources to study up on subclassing and hooks? My question is answeres; however, I would still like to learn more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "sub-classing a window".  It is a standard Windows programming technique to allow modifying the behavior of a window whose code you cannot modify.  Like the built-in Button class in your case.

There are several details, like sub-classing a specific instance of a window vs global sub-classing.  And super-classing, a technique that ensures the window gets customized before it is created.  This is all well described in the [SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#winproc_subclassing) and any book about native winapi programming.  Like Petzold's "Programming Windows", required reading if you want to hack winapi code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused. According to the documentation, GWLP_WNDPROC changes the window procedure for the specified window, so any future messages sent to that window will go to the new procedure. It doesn't "grab the current message" in any sense that I'm aware of.